# What do I need for a java SSL (HTTPS) connection

Tags: java, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, cmis

I am new to code signing and certificates. Short description: I connect to a Alfresco repository to download some documents to the client using OpenCMIS. Everything is working fine until I tested is with our test server which uses SSL (HTTPS Url) connections. Here I get an exception

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I have no experience with such things and dont know what I have to do so my application is running properly? I have read I have to use the certificate or a truststore or something? But what exactly I need to do? Can someone help me please?

EDIT: I should have mentioned that I am developing a java web start application. Is there a solution in which I dont have to manually install the certificate to the local truststore?

EDIT2: Okay since I have to import the certificate on every computer this is no longer an option and I will use the workaround which ignores the verification of the certificate.

Thank you anyways guys!!!

Comment: I can use a workaround to ignore the validation but this should not be used i production

Comment: Is this even a programming question?

Comment: As I mentiond I have no idea. But you can be right. I dont know.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i tried this long back for similar problem, and was working.

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", ""); 
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", ""); 
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "");
Security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation", "true");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", ""); 
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", ""); 
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", ""); 
System.setProperty("sun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation", "true");
```

Also the same can be achieved by configuring the `trustore` and `keystore` in the application server you are using.

Issue is with certificates not getting imported correctly.
I hope below links will help you out.

[Link1](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target/)

[Link2](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAKB/Unable+to+Connect+to+SSL+Services+due+to+PKIX+Path+Building+Failed+sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException)

Comment: so keystore should map to the root certificat of the server? and truststore to the client side truststore?

Comment: @Pali yes correct
If it solves your problem, please accept the answer